# OpenIddict: How to register signing key in the resource server for validating tokens?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, jwt, authorization, openiddict

I use OpenIddict. I want to sign the token with the symmetric key. I have configured my authorization server to use OpenIddict. Here is the code in the Startup file.

```
services.AddOpenIddict()

            .AddServer(options =>
            {
                options.SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token");

                options.AllowPasswordFlow()
                       .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

                options.AcceptAnonymousClients(); 

                options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
                       .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate()
                       .DisableAccessTokenEncryption();

                options.UseAspNetCore();

                options.RegisterScopes(OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.OfflineAccess);  //This is for grant_type=refresh_token.

                options.EnableDegradedMode();

                options.AddEventHandler<ValidateTokenRequestContext>(c => c.UseSingletonHandler<TokenRequestValidator>());

                options.AddEventHandler<HandleTokenRequestContext>(c => c.UseSingletonHandler<TokenRequestHandler>());

                var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("b14ca5898a4e4133bbce2ea2315a1916")); //this is for example

                options.AddSigningKey(key);
            });
```

When I receive the token from the authorization server and make calls to the resource server, it responds with 401 Unauthorized.

Here is the code in the resource server's startup file.

```
 services.AddOpenIddict().AddValidation(options =>
        {

            // Register the ASP.NET Core host.
            options.UseAspNetCore();

            options.UseSystemNetHttp();

            options.SetIssuer("https://localhost:44340/");

        });
```

Please help me to properly set configurations.

Comment: Are there any logs either in the server or in the client which tell you more about what is misconfigured? Did you go through the OpenIDDict documentation and examples to make sure that you have everything configured properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a symmetric key for token validation, you'll need to register it in the OpenIddict validation options as symmetric keys are not exposed by the discovery endpoints.

```cs
services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.Configure(o => o.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey = key);
    });
```